# Python Parsing Dictionary within a Dictionary from JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, decode

I have a json file that contains an object with a dictionary within it:

```
{
   "__class__": "monster",
   "name": "Mugger",
   "level": 1,
   "hpTotal": 20,
   "attacks": ["Sword", "Knife"],
   "stats": {
       "AC": 12,
       "STR": 11,
       "DEX": 12,
       "CON": 12,
       "INT": 10,
       "WIS": 10,
       "CHA": 10
   }
}
```

I load it with the following function:

```
def loadCharacters(fileLoc):
    with open(fileLoc) as character_data:
        data = character_data.read()
        characterDictionary = json.loads(data, object_hook=decode_character)
    return characterDictionary
```

When i parse it through my decoder it is giving me a KeyError based on Class:

```
# Decode characters based on class
def decode_character(dct):
    if dct['__class__'] == 'npc':
        return character(dct["name"], dct["level"], dct["hpTotal"])
    if dct['__class__'] == 'monster':
        return monster(dct["name"], dct["level"], dct["hpTotal"], dct["attacks"], dct["stats"])
    raise ValueError("Not a valid character dictionary")
```

Traceback report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SRC\Testing\ImportCharacters.py", line 14, in <module>
    characterRoster = loadCharacters(characterFileLoc)
  File "C:SRC\Characters\LoadCharacter.py", line 30, in loadCharacters
    characterDictionary = json.loads(data, object_hook=decode_character)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "C:\SRC\Characters\LoadCharacter.py", line 12, in decode_character
    if dct['__class__'] == 'npc':
KeyError: '__class__'
```

I think that it is trying to parse the dictionary within the object.
How do i get the whole object parsed and not just the sub dictionary?

Comment: Can we see your `character` and `Monster` code ?

Comment: where are you getting the error? can you share the error and traceback?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar They are just classes with __init__ that take those variables. nothing exciting happening there.

Comment: @akshat I've added the traceback now

Comment: Are you you sure you are passing the right `dictionary/decoded json object` ? I can only reproduce your error if I pass a different dictionary to the function `decode_character` than the one you have defined above.

Comment: You must check if outer dictionary is in a list or not.. Or you must share the code from which you are getting this json response.

Comment: I've added the function used to laod the json file. I know, once I remove the inner dictionary and replace it with a string it will work correctly. It's only since it's introduction that I'm getting errors. The monster/character object will take a string or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that you always expect the item `__class__` to exist although it does not happen.

With the json-data you provide the function `decode_character` will be called twice:

- One with the root json-object data. With keys `__class__`, `name`, `level`, etc.
- Once more with the inner json-object data. With keys `AC`, `STR`, etc.

I do not really know what you expect from you code but I would change the `dct['__class__']` for `dct.get('__clas__')` so that a KeyError is not arisen.

[Here](https://repl.it/@kazbeel/SO-50019680) you can see an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I can see what's happening now. However, when I try and implement it in my environment, it's still passing them one at a time. So I still can't pass the "Stats" dictionary to my object